# Don't know how to convert the Django field skills (<class 'taggit.managers.TaggableManager'>)? graphql

Tags: python, django, tags, graphql, django-taggit

I am trying to change my `rest` end points to `graphql` and I had a library called `TaggableManager` as one of the `model fields`.  Anyone know how this can work with graphql?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16):

You have to explicitly tell graphene how to convert the `TaggableManger` field to be used in Queries. Register `@convert_django_field` from `graphene_django.converter` before using your model with the `TaggableManger` field either in `Queries` or `Mutations`.

Example:

```
from graphene_django.converter import convert_django_field
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

# convert TaggableManager to string representation
@convert_django_field.register(TaggableManager)
def convert_field_to_string(field, registry=None):
    return String(description=field.help_text, required=not field.null)
```

Comment: I am getting "tags": "catalog.Product.None". Not working!

Answer (score 11):

I made one version of the [Deepak Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424888/deepak-sood) answer what works for me

```py
from graphene import String, List
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from graphene_django.converter import convert_django_field

@convert_django_field.register(TaggableManager)
def convert_field_to_string(field, registry=None):
    return List(String, source='get_tags')
```

And in the tagger model, i create a property names get_tags:

```py
    .
    .
    .
    tags = TaggableManager()

    @property
    def get_tags(self):
        return self.tags.all()
```

Comment: By the way this should most likely be placed in the class that inherits **graphene_django.DjangoObjectType** .

Comment: Another approach to avoid having to add a `get_tags` property
```    return graphene.List(
        graphene.String,
        description=field.help_text,
        required=not field.null,
        resolver=lambda obj, info: obj.tags.all()
    )
```