# Graphene_django can not use <class 'taggit.managers.TaggableManager'> field

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

the best way to used tagged.managers.TaggableManager with Graphql graphene_django?
where I try to use a model with taggableManager Field, Graphql displays the following error:
Don't know how to convert the Django field app.Asset.keywords (<class 'taggit.managers.TaggableManager'>)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47166385/17093315

Comment: yes, thanks. I have used it. but the second answer was actually useful.